# Update of SQLite database results in error

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am new to Android and working on an app, that should retrieve data from the camera and store it into an SQlite database. Unfortunately, the database update is not working, so any hints or comments would be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
package de.die_web_agenten.www.runinstant;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

import de.die_web_agenten.www.runinstant.db.TaskContract;
import de.die_web_agenten.www.runinstant.db.TaskDBHelper;


public class AndroidBarcodeQrExample extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    static final String ACTION_SCAN = "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN";
    private ListAdapter listAdapter;
    private TaskDBHelper helper;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_barcode);
    }

    public void scanBar(View v) {
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_SCAN);
            intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            showDialog(AndroidBarcodeQrExample.this, "No Scanner Found", "Download a scanner code activity?", "Yes", "No").show();
        }
    }

    public void scanQR(View v) {
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_SCAN);
            intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            showDialog(AndroidBarcodeQrExample.this, "No Scanner Found", "Download a scanner code activity?", "Yes", "No").show();
        }
    }

    private static AlertDialog showDialog(final Activity act, CharSequence title, CharSequence message, CharSequence buttonYes, CharSequence buttonNo) {
        AlertDialog.Builder downloadDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(act);
        downloadDialog.setTitle(title);
        downloadDialog.setMessage(message);
        downloadDialog.setPositiveButton(buttonYes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://search?q=pname:" + "com.google.zxing.client.android");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                try {
                    act.startActivity(intent);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {

                }
            }
        });
        downloadDialog.setNegativeButton(buttonNo, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            }
        });
        return downloadDialog.show();
    }

    private void updateUI() {
        helper = new TaskDBHelper(AndroidBarcodeQrExample.this);
        SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = sqlDB.query(TaskContract.TABLE,
                new String[]{ TaskContract.Columns.SCAN_RESULT, TaskContract.Columns.SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT,TaskContract.Columns._id,
                         TaskContract.Columns.DATE},
                null, null, null, null, null
        );


        listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this,
                R.layout.task_view,
                cursor,
                new String[]{TaskContract.Columns.SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT, TaskContract.Columns.SCAN_RESULT, TaskContract.Columns._id},
                new int[]{R.id.taskTextView},
                0
        );

        this.setListAdapter(listAdapter);

    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
                helper = new TaskDBHelper(AndroidBarcodeQrExample.this);
                SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                //values.clear();
                values.put(TaskContract.Columns.SCAN_RESULT, contents);
                values.put(TaskContract.Columns.SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT, format);
                db.insertWithOnConflict(TaskContract.TABLE, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
                //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Content:" + contents + " Format:" + format, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                //toast.show();
                /*Intent SecondIntent = new Intent(AndroidBarcodeQrExample.this, SecondListActivity.class);
                SecondIntent.putExtra("SCAN_RESULT", contents);
                startActivity(SecondIntent);*/
                //Intent SecondIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SecondListActivity.class);
                //intent.putExtra("SCAN_RESULT", contents);
                //intent.putExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT", format);
                //Intent i = new Intent(this,  SecondListActivity.class);
                //startActivityForResult(i, 1);
                //startActivity(SecondIntent);
                Log.d("ADebugTag", "Value: " + (contents));
                Log.d("BDebugTag", "Value: " + (format));
                //updateUI();

            //Context context = getApplicationContext();
            //CharSequence text = "Informationen erfolgreich gespeichert!";
            //int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            }

        }

    }

    public void setListAdapter(ListAdapter listAdapter) {
        this.listAdapter = listAdapter;
    }

}
```

Here´s the TaskDBHelper class:

```
package de.die_web_agenten.www.runinstant.db;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;


public class TaskDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public TaskDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, TaskContract.DB_NAME, null, TaskContract.DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqlDB) {
        String sqlQuery =
                String.format("CREATE TABLE %s (" +
                        "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + "%s TEXT, %s TEXT)",
                                    TaskContract.TABLE,
                                    TaskContract.Columns.SCAN_RESULT,
                                    TaskContract.Columns.SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT
                                    );
        Log.d("TaskDBHelper", "Query to form table: " + sqlQuery);
        sqlDB.execSQL(sqlQuery);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqlDB, int i, int i2) {
        sqlDB.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TaskContract.TABLE);
        onCreate(sqlDB);
    }
}
```

Here´s the TaskContract class:

```
    package de.die_web_agenten.www.runinstant.db;

    public class TaskContract {
        public static final String DB_NAME = "de.die_web_agenten.www.runinstant";
        public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
        public static final String TABLE = "VALUES";


        public static class Columns {
            public static final String SCAN_RESULT = "SCAN_RESULT";
            public static final String SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT = "SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT";
            //public static final String DATE = "date";
            public static final String _id = "_id";
        }
    }

Here´s the TaskDBHelper class: 

package de.die_web_agenten.www.runinstant.db;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;


public class TaskDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public TaskDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, TaskContract.DB_NAME, null, TaskContract.DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqlDB) {
        String sqlQuery =
                String.format("CREATE TABLE %s (" +
                        "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + "%s TEXT, %s TEXT)",
                                    TaskContract.TABLE,
                                    TaskContract.Columns.SCAN_RESULT,
                                    TaskContract.Columns.SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT
                                    );
        Log.d("TaskDBHelper", "Query to form table: " + sqlQuery);
        sqlDB.execSQL(sqlQuery);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqlDB, int i, int i2) {
        sqlDB.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TaskContract.TABLE);
        onCreate(sqlDB);
    }
}
```

Here´s the logcat:

```
08-15 16:55:12.356 15118-15118/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: de.die_web_agenten.www.runinstant, PID: 15118
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {de.die_web_agenten.www.runinstant/de.die_web_agenten.www.runinstant.AndroidBarcodeQrExample}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN flg=0x80000 (has extras) }} to activity {de.die_web_agenten.www.runinstant/de.die_web_agenten.www.runinstant.AndroidBarcodeQrExample}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "VALUES": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE VALUES (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, SCAN_RESULT TEXT, SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT TEXT)
                                                   #################################################################
                                                   Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
                                                   Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
                                                    (near "VALUES": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE VALUES (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, SCAN_RESULT TEXT, SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT TEXT))
                                                   #################################################################
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3440)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2774)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1430)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN flg=0x80000 (has extras) }} to activity {de.die_web_agenten.www.runinstant/de.die_web_agenten.www.runinstant.AndroidBarcodeQrExample}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "VALUES": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE VALUES (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, SCAN_RESULT TEXT, SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT TEXT)
                                                   #################################################################
                                                   Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
                                                   Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
                                                    (near "VALUES": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE VALUES (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, SCAN_RESULT TEXT, SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT TEXT))
                                                   #################################################################
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4005)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3395)
                                                        ... 11 more
                                                    Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "VALUES": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE VALUES (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, SCAN_RESULT TEXT, SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT TEXT)
                                                   #################################################################
                                                   Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
                                                   Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
                                                    (near "VALUES": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE VALUES (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, SCAN_RESULT TEXT, SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT TEXT))
                                                   #################################################################
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1093)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:670)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: The error exception is very informative; problem is inside your onResume method;

Comment: The error is in your `TaskDBHelper`, you'll need to post that code. Thanks!

Comment: Also, now days, we extend AppCompatActivity, not the regular Activity class

Comment: Thank you for the comments so far- ok, so what is the problem with the onResume method, @Eenvincible? I added the TaskDBHelper class, @TR4Android. Any further hints would be appreciated.

Comment: `Caused by: java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier: s` This is the relevant error message. You are formatting a string, and have 1 less parameters than format placeholders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error ocurrs because the number of expected placeholder `String`s does not match the number of given format `String`s:

The following `String` should be formatted (expects 6 `String`s to fill in the placeholders):

```
"CREATE TABLE %s (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT)"
```

You have given it 3 `String`s:

```
TaskContract.TABLE, TaskContract.Columns.SCAN_RESULT, TaskContract.Columns.SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT
```

Chances are you just need to pass the column names required to the `String.format()` method, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Ok, thanks so far. Now I updated the TaskDBHelper class accordingly and I still do get the same error. Any more hints would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Update your TaskDBHelper class in your question, please. Thanks.

Comment: String sqlQuery =
                String.format("CREATE TABLE %s (" +
                        "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                        "%s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT)",
                                    TaskContract.TABLE,
                                    TaskContract.Columns.SCAN_RESULT,
                                    TaskContract.Columns.SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT
                                    );
    
   That´s the part I updated, also in the question @TR4Android - is it correct?

Comment: You're still missing one column, there are 3 columns in your CREATE statement (`%s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT`), but only 2 in your format strings (`TaskContract.Columns‌​.SCAN_RESULT, TaskContract.Columns‌​.SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT`).

Comment: @ TR4Android - thank you very much so far - now I fixed all the issues and still get errors in the Logcat. I changed the question and added the new Logcat error. Any further hints or comments would be appreciated.

Comment: `VALUES` is a reserved keyword in SQL, use another table name instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is the problematic part: 2 more parameters needed. You have 5 placeholders and 3 of them filled...

```
   String sqlQuery =
            String.format("CREATE TABLE %s (" +
              "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
              "%s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT)",
              TaskContract.TABLE,
              TaskContract.Columns.SCAN_RESULT,
              TaskContract.Columns.SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT
                // 2 more to go!!
              );
```

Also take note: using String manipulation is generally not the recommended way to create SQL queries, even though in this code, all input seems to come from inside the application.

Comment: Ok, thanks so far. Now I updated the TaskDBHelper class accordingly and I still do get the same error. Any more hints would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: @DWA2112 Please add an update with the changed part. Is the error message completely the same - i.e. does it complain for the same line?